# Como exibir dados JSON em jQuery DataTables via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Minha tabela não está sendo carregada com os dados que estão no meu arquivo JSON, como tenho pouca experiência não sei o que está havendo de errado.

Meu arquivo JSON está no mesmo diretório que se encontra a página web em questão, esse é meu arquivo JSON.

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "wladimir bandeira",
        "gender": "Male",
        "designation": "Manager",
        "age": "38"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "wladimir bandeira",
        "gender": "Male",
        "designation": "Manager",
        "age": "38"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "wladimir bandeira",
        "gender": "Male",
        "designation": "Manager",
        "age": "38"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "wladimir bandeira",
        "gender": "Male",
        "designation": "Manager",
        "age": "38"
    }
]
```

**mockingTest.json**

Esse é meu arquivo HTML;

```
<%@ include file="/pages/template/imports.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Não Conformidade</h1> 
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pesquisa" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Pesquisar</button>
        <c:if test="${resultPage.sizeResult != 0}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Gerar PDF" onclick="gerarPdf();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Gerar PDF</button>
        </c:if>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="employee_table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Designation</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON("mockingTest.json", function(data){ 
     var employee_data = '';
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
          employee_data += '<tr>';
          employee_data += '<td>'+value.name+'</td>';
          employee_data += '<td>'+value.gender+'</td>';
          employee_data += '<td>'+value.designation+'</td>';
          employee_data += '</tr>';
      });
      $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);    
  });
 });




 </script> 

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

O meu arquivo jquery é da versão 3 **jquery-3.4.1.min.js** e está importada da forma correta, a parte que está errada é essa debaixo;

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON("mockingTest.json", function(data){ 
     var employee_data = '';
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
          employee_data += '<tr>';
          employee_data += '<td>'+value.name+'</td>';
          employee_data += '<td>'+value.gender+'</td>';
          employee_data += '<td>'+value.designation+'</td>';
          employee_data += '</tr>';
      });
      $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);    
  });
 });




 </script>
```

Como faço para corrigir e as informações do arquivo JSON aparece na tabela em tela?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A estrutura da tabela está errada. De acordo com a [documentação](https://datatables.net/manual/installation), a estrutura da tabela deve ser basicamente:

```
<table id="id_da_tabela">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>texto</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>texto</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Repare que na sua tabela falta o `thead` e o `tbody`, e é no `tbody` aonde você deve fazer o `.append()`:

```
$('#employee_table tbody').append(employee_data);
```

Outra coisa, você está fazendo append com um número de colunas menor do que existe na tabela, e isso resulta em erro. Repare que você colocou 5 colunas `<th>` e está fazendo append de apenas 3:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
    employee_data += '<tr>';
    // FALTAM 2 COLUNAS PARA FECHAR 5
    employee_data += '<td>'+value.name+'</td>';
    employee_data += '<td>'+value.gender+'</td>';
    employee_data += '<td>'+value.designation+'</td>';
    employee_data += '</tr>';
});
```

Fazendo essas correções, seu código irá funcionar perfeitamente.

> Como bem observado na resposta do Mauro Roberto, pelo código postado
>   na pergunta, parece que você está carregando o jQuery depois do
>   script. Com isso o `$( document ).ready(function() {` vai dar erro
>   porque nesse ponto do script o jQuery ainda não está na memória.

Se o descrito acima for mais um problema, você pode trocar o:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

por:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Você precisa incluir o `jquery` antes do seu código. Basta mudar a ordem da seguinte forma:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON("mockingTest.json", function(data){ 
     var employee_data = '';
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
          employee_data += '<tr>';
          employee_data += '<td>'+value.name+'</td>';
          employee_data += '<td>'+value.gender+'</td>';
          employee_data += '<td>'+value.designation+'</td>';
          employee_data += '</tr>';
      });
      $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);    
  });
 });
 </script>
```

Talvez depois você vá ter problema de *cross origin* por causa da requisição ao `json`. Olhe o console do navegar caso dê algum erro...

Irei deixar uma referência sobre:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224017/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-in-chrome-why